# How can I disable a layout behind my SlidingDrawer in Android?

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I have a SlidingDrawer that pops up from the bottom of the screen and fills the screen about 80%. Even though the SlidingDrawer view is in focus, it is still possible to click on items, buttons and other elements in the view that is behind the SlidingDrawer. When SlidingDrawer is active/pulled up/in focus, I want to disable the entire view behind it so it will not be able to recieve clicks and touches. Is there a good way to disable an entire view? I have tried `setEnable(false)` and `setClickable(false)` but neither of them work.

Answer (score 0):

Grab the `LinearLayout` that holds the contents and add a click listener. Have the click listener respond to clicks (throw away, whatever) - and this then stops it propagating to the view below the sliding drawer - it works for me - and it doesn't block the other items in the drawer.

Other way is to put `SlidingDrawer` in the `RelativeLayout`, instead of `LinearLayout`. And set `mySlidingDrawer.bringToFront()` in opening method.

Comment: Did you specify about the mapview in your question ?